# Xcode tableview images load again and again

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    // Rounded Rect for cell image
    CALayer *cellImageLayer = cell.imageView.layer;
    [cellImageLayer setCornerRadius:35];
    [cellImageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {


        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_ResimAdi[indexPath.row]]];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        if (image) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {

                    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
                    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    [cell setNeedsLayout];

                }
            });
        }
    });

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _OUrArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

When i scroll up or scroll back images loading again and again i have no lagging when i scroll but i want to load my images into cache so my app does not load my image again.(i want to twitter scrolls)

Comment: Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) its a good library and it will cache your image also.

Comment: You can use SDWebImage or write custom cache using NSCache

Comment: you know any tutorial about SDWebImage ?

Comment: Of course they are loading, cellForRow gets called for every dequeued cell. You need to write your image to the disk when you load it, and before you go and download it again just check if you have it on disc, if yes then show that one if not then download and write to disc.

Comment: I know we have to load images but how :) Im try to use NSUserDefaults but probably not work on images

Comment: hello your issues is Solved or not???

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice category: UIImageView + AFNetworking, wich is dooing everything for you. Just add the AFNetworking pod, and use

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;


 [image setImageWithUrl:@"yourURL"];
```

and this method will take care of everything.